# Webservice Query to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, web-services

**The problem**

I need to extract information from a web service that is hosted here
https://fogos.icnf.pt/localizador/webserviceocorrencias.asp

The web service accepts various queries like:
https://fogos.icnf.pt/localizador/webserviceocorrencias.asp?ano=2021&mes=5&distrito=faro

Where `ano` is year and `distrito` is district

This will return all events in 2021 for the Faro district

**How can I import this into a pandas dataframe? Any ideas?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse XML and create a DataFrame from XML tree elements:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

# get data
resp = requests.get(
    'https://fogos.icnf.pt/localizador/webserviceocorrencias.asp?ano=2021&mes=5&distrito=faro')

# parse XML
et = ElementTree.parse(io.StringIO(resp.text))

# create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {f.tag: f.text for f in e.findall('./')} for e in et.findall('./')]
)

df
```

Output:

```
   DISTRITO       TIPO   ANO AREAPOV AREAMATO AREAAGRIC AREATOTAL  \
0      Faro   Agrícola  2021       0        0    0.0344    0.0344   
1      Faro  Florestal  2021       4      0.5         0       4.5   
2      Faro  Florestal  2021       0    0.026         0     0.026   
3      Faro  Florestal  2021       0   0.3577         0    0.3577   
4      Faro   Agrícola  2021       0        0    0.0919    0.0919   
5      Faro   Agrícola  2021       0        0    0.0794    0.0794   
6      Faro   Agrícola  2021       0        0     0.073     0.073   
7      Faro  Florestal  2021       0   0.0257         0    0.0257   
8      Faro  Florestal  2021       0   0.2447         0    0.2447   
9      Faro  Florestal  2021       0   0.0554         0    0.0554   
10     Faro   Agrícola  2021       0        0     0.003     0.003   
...
```